# JSON gets replaced

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, discord, discord.py

hi I have a problem I can save data in my JSON my its replace it when I type my command you can help me? please

My code :

```py
async def get_bank_data(): 
    with open("assets/bdd/mainbank.json", "r+") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users

async def open_account(user, guild):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(guild.id)] = {}

    if str(user.id) in users[str(guild.id)]:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(guild.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(guild.id)][str(user.id)]["cash"] = 5000
        users[str(guild.id)][str(user.id)]["bank"] = 10000

    with open ("assets/bdd/mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    return True

@client.command(pass_content=True)
async def create_account(ctx, user:discord.Member = None):
    if user == None:
      user = ctx.author
    else:
      user = user

    guild = ctx.guild

    await open_account(user, guild)

    await ctx.send("Your account has been created !")
```

My json :

[image]

Thank you

Comment: If you can post text as actual text, it will always be better. Try not to post text as images. Also, you should provide a clearer step to reproduce the issue you're facing. You should also describe your problem more precisely. For example, what is replaced? What do you mean by "I typed my command"? e.g. When the function open_account is called, it overwrite my JSON file content, how do I make it so that it won't replace the content in my JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
with open("assets/bdd/mainbank.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users,f)
```

you overwrite `f` with the new contents. Instead you want to read the existing json, update it with the new values, then write it back to the file, like this:

```
with open("assets/bdd/mainbank.json", "r+") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    data.update(users)
    json.dump(data,f)
```

Edit:
I missed that you already have a `get_bank_data` function. I believe the issue is that you wipe the entire guilds bank each time you want to add a user with:
`users[str(guild.id)] = {}`
You should check first to see if the guild.id doesn't already exist:

```
if str(guild.id) not in users.keys():
    users[str(guild.id)] = {}
```

Comment: `{}{"871682135474458664": {"560849136899850261": {"cash": 5000, "bank": 10000}}}`

there is an error

Comment: Don't use the first changes I suggested, only the last one.

Comment: [link]https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/871682135474458668/872404669207560252/c.PNG

Dont work

Comment: Looks like you've deleted the json and are trying to read an empty file, `users = json.load(f)` will throw an exception if the file is completely empty. As a quick fix just manally add `{}` to the empty json.

Comment: I tried your method and others but it still doesn't work

Comment: You'll have to be more specific in what's not working and exactly how you want it to work.